# Error importing node module through Webpack, "You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type"

Tags: javascript, webpack, babeljs, quill

I'm trying to build a module that extends the Quill editor, and integrate it with my project.

When I try to import specific Quill modules within my custom Quill module, webpack throws an error:

```
Uncaught Error: Cannot find module "quill/core/quill"
    at webpackMissingModule (QuillLinkTooltip.js:15)
    at eval (QuillLinkTooltip.js:15)
```

and then later on:

```
./~/quill/core/quill.js
Module parse failed: /Users/path_to_my_app_folder/node_modules/quill/core/quill.js Line 1: Unexpected token
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| import './polyfill';
| import Delta from 'quill-delta';
| import Editor from './editor';
```

Here's an excerpt from the custom Quill module (`QuillLinkTooltip.js`) that I am building and that throw errors:

```
import Quill from 'quill/core/quill';
import { Range } from 'quill/core/selection';
import Keyboard from 'quill/modules/keyboard';
import LinkBlot from 'quill/formats/link';
import Tooltip from 'quill/ui/tooltip';
```

I am using Webpack, babel and babel es2015 preset within my project. I can import other node modules such as lodash by using something like `import get from 'lodash/get';`.

I'm suspecting webpack can find the module, but is having difficulty in parsing it. Here's an excerpt of my webpack.config.js file:

```
module: {
    loaders: [
        {
            test: /.*\.js$/,
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            exclude: [ /node_modules/, /frontend/ ],
            query: {
                presets: [ 'babel-preset-es2015' ].map(require.resolve),
                plugins: [ 'babel-plugin-add-module-exports' ].map(require.resolve)
            }
        },
```

I've read https://quilljs.com/guides/adding-quill-to-your-build-pipeline/ which mentions that Webback, Babel and Babel ES2015 preset are needed, so it seems I have the right webpack setup. But maybe I'm missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to get this to work. Turned out my webpack.config.js file was excluding node_modules from the babel-loader definition, so Webpack would try to resolve quill files placed in /node_modules, but wouldn't be able to parse them as they were excluded from the babel-loader.

Fixed it by adding an exception to my exclude statement:

```
module: {
    loaders: [
        {
            test: /.*\.js$/,
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            exclude: [ /node_modules(?!\/quill)/, /frontend/ ],
            query: {
                presets: [ 'babel-preset-es2015' ].map(require.resolve),
                plugins: [ 'babel-plugin-add-module-exports' ].map(require.resolve)
            }
        },
```